# Ergonomic PC mouse for left handed child?

Tags: wireless, mice, ergonomics

I've been looking for a good mouse device for my son around but it's not so easy to find a PC/laptop mouse which is:

- ergonomic and lightweight
- small for a 12 yrs person (okay the hand will start growing)
- wireless
- designed for a left-handed person
- robust
- long battery life
- not necessarily special gaming features but, of course, nice to have

Can be of some alternative ergonomic design if it feels well.

Budget: up to $100.

Any ideas?

Comment: Listing a budget will likely help you get more relevant results.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for the "[Razer Deathadder Left-Handed Edition](https://www.razer.com/gaming-mice/razer-deathadder-left-hand-edition)".

I've been using it for many years now and it still works like a charm. It's great for gaming as well as regular school work.

Read PCGamer's test on [the best left-handed mouse for gaming](https://www.pcgamer.com/the-best-left-handed-mouse-for-gaming-for-2019/).

You can find the corded version for around $40-70 at e.g. [Insight](https://www.insight.com/en_US/shop/product/RZ01-00151700-W1M1/RAZERUSA/RZ01-00151700-W1M1/RazerDeathAdder-LeftHandEdition-mouse-left-handed-infrared-5buttons-wired-USB/) or [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000256430813.html).

Answer (score 2):

I use a right-handed, corded version of the Adesso iMouse (the E1).  The iMouse E90 is a cordless left-handed version.

https://www.adesso.com/product/imouse-e90-wireless-left-handed-vertical-ergonomic-mouse/

It has 5 buttons and a scroll-wheel.  MSRP: $50.